# How to pattern match on a Prop when proving in Coq without elimination on Type

Tags: coq, dependent-type, theorem-proving, type-theory, lean

I'm trying to prove that the tail of a sorted list is sorted in Coq, using pattern matching instead of tactics:

```
Require Import Coq.Sorting.Sorted.

Definition tail_also_sorted {A : Prop} {R : relation A} {h : A} {t : list A} 
                            (H: Sorted R (h::t)) : Sorted R t :=
match H in Sorted _ (h::t) return Sorted _ t with
  | Sorted_nil _ => Sorted_nil R
  | Sorted_cons rest_sorted _ => rest_sorted
end.
```

This fails however, with:

```
Error:
Incorrect elimination of "H" in the inductive type "Sorted":
the return type has sort "Type" while it should be "Prop".
Elimination of an inductive object of sort Prop
is not allowed on a predicate in sort Type
because proofs can be eliminated only to build proofs.
```

I suspect it's possible in the underlying Calculus, as the following Lean code type-checks, and Lean is also built upon the CIC:

```
inductive is_sorted {α: Type} [decidable_linear_order α] : list α -> Prop
| is_sorted_zero : is_sorted []
| is_sorted_one : ∀ (x: α), is_sorted [x]
| is_sorted_many : ∀ {x y: α} {ys: list α}, x < y -> is_sorted (y::ys) -> is_sorted (x::y::ys)

lemma tail_also_sorted {α: Type} [decidable_linear_order α] : ∀ {h: α} {t: list α}, 
                                 is_sorted (h::t) -> is_sorted t
| _ [] _ := is_sorted.is_sorted_zero
| _ (y::ys) (is_sorted.is_sorted_many _ rest_sorted) := rest_sorted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug. The problem, I think, is in the following part:

```
in Sorted _ (h::t)
```

In pure CIC, this kind of annotation on `match` expressions is not allowed. Instead, you are required to write something like this:

```
Definition tail_also_sorted {A : Prop} {R : relation A} {h : A} {t : list A}
                            (H: Sorted R (h::t)) : Sorted R t :=
match H in Sorted _ t'
        return match t' return Prop with
               | [] => True
               | h :: t => Sorted R t
               end with
| Sorted_nil _ => I
| Sorted_cons rest_sorted _ => rest_sorted
end.
```

The difference is that the index in the `in` clause is now a fresh variable that is bound in the `return` clause.  To relieve you from having to write such horrible programs, Coq allows you to put slightly more complicated expressions in `in` clauses than generic variables, like the one you had. To avoid compromising soundness, this extension is actually compiled down to core CIC terms. I imagine that there is a bug somewhere is this translation that is producing the following term instead:

```
Definition tail_also_sorted {A : Prop} {R : relation A} {h : A} {t : list A}
                            (H: Sorted R (h::t)) : Sorted R t :=
match H in Sorted _ t'
        return match t' return Type with
               | [] => True
               | h :: t => Sorted R t
               end with
| Sorted_nil _ => I
| Sorted_cons rest_sorted _ => rest_sorted
end.
```

Notice the `return Type` annotation. Indeed, if you try to enter this snippet in Coq, you get exactly the same error message as the one you saw.

Comment: Where would be the best place to report the issue?